# Can't set textlabel cell

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, sdk

Here is my code

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *category;

@synthesize category;

NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"categorylist" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString * content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    self.category = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
    [content release];
```

and It has error here

```
cell.textLabel.text = [category objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
```

I'm newbie. so Please help me find out the solution please.

v
v
v
From many help This is finalize solution code.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *category;

@synthesize category;

NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"categorylist" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString * content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    self.category = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```

and here

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't release content. If you didn't use `alloc`, `new`, `retain` or `copy` you are not allowed to release.

You should read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) again

Comment: Oh Thank , I remove release too.

Answer (score 0):

From your code everything is correct ..may be bug behind the following thing

1.Check your category array wethere it contain value by printing

```
NSLog(@"%@", category);
```

2.Did u inform  ur array count to `numberOfRowsInSection` function

3.Did u release category array's memory in `dealloc`

4.Did U set `datasource` for tableview???

Best Regards

Comment: @Astaln enopi
I check category and It's can store text from text file. And I already release category in dealloc. But I don't know What am I should do in numberofrowintransaction. 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 15;
}
here is numberOfRowsInSection of my code. By the way I have 15 line in my textfile. Very thank for your help. :)

Comment: did your  array(category) read text file perfectly ?????.did u try to print your array for debugging

Comment: Wow I kill the BUG!!! by change it to this
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: great post ur answer for new guy's reference

Comment: good that you have covered the bug in some memory management voodoo that only works by coincidence.